# remove tag and contents based on child tag value - python lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to locate a particular tag, based on it child's contents and remove the parent tag and contents, but cant find an answer. Here is my xml:

```
<video>
    <crew>
      <member billing="top">
        <name>Some Guy</name>
        <roles>
          <role>Painter</role>
          <role>Decorator</role>
        </roles>
      </crew>
      <crew billing="top">
        <name>Another Guy</name>
        <roles>
          <role>Primary</role>
        </roles>
      </crew>
    </crew>
</video>
```

What I want to do is search to see if the `<role>Primary</role>` exists in a `<crew>` block, if it does I want to delete the whole `<crew>` block which the `<role>Primary</role>` exists in, it's parent.
So the result would be:

```
<video>
    <crew>
      <member billing="top">
        <name>Some Guy</name>
        <roles>
          <role>Painter</role>
          <role>Decorator</role>
        </roles>
      </crew>
</video>
```

It's sometimes not at the end and maybe buried within many other `<crew>` tags, so I know that if that  block contains `<role>Primary</role>` I want to remove that whole `<crew>` block it resides in.
I have tried:

```
for find1 in root.iter(tag='role'):
    find1 = find1.text
    if find1 == "Primary":
        path = tree.xpath('//video/crew')
        etree.strip_elements(path, 'member')
```

but this removes every `<crew>` tag and it's contents.
Kind regards.

Comment: Given xml is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using xpath:

```
for crew in root.xpath('.//crew[descendant::role[contains(text(), "Primary")]]'):
    crew.getparent().remove(crew)
```

Comment: That works, BUT removes BOTH crews, I only want to remove the one with  Primary in it.

Comment: @user2446702, With the xml given in the question, my answer code remove only `Another Guy`.